# Why is this code not scrolling to positioned class on keydown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$(document).bind("keydown",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#show-all-win").animate({
       scrollLeft: $(".key_"+e.keyCode).position().left
    }, 800);
})
```

Comment: can you provide your css style and html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).bind("keydown",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#show-all-win").animate({
     "scrollLeft": "-=" + $(".key_"+e.keyCode).position().left + "px"
   }, 800);
});
```

Hope this helps